# Rendering a random noise CALayer with Core Image is generating strange artifacts

Tags: ios, core-image, noise, cifilter, ciimage

I am programmatically creating a `CALayer` subclass which applies a bit of pixel noise to itself. The code works in that it renders noise in the layer, but there is a strange artifact on the image that I am unable to determine the root cause.

Here is a sample image with the `noiseOpacity` turned up to make the problem more visible.

[image]

The pink box is a `UANoisyGradientLayer`, a `CAGradientLayer` subclass with the following bits:

```
@interface UANoisyGradientLayer ()
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CIContext *noiseContext;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CIFilter  *noiseGenerator;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CIImage   *noiseImage;
@end

@implementation UANoisyGradientLayer

@synthesize noiseOpacity = _noiseOpacity, noiseImage;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.noiseOpacity = 0.10;
        self.noiseContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];         
        self.noiseGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
        [self.noiseGenerator setValue:[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"] valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [self.noiseGenerator setDefaults];

        self.noiseImage = [self.noiseGenerator outputImage];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    [super drawInContext:ctx];

    CGRect extentRect = [self.noiseImage extent];
    if (CGRectIsInfinite(extentRect) || CGRectIsEmpty(extentRect)) {
        extentRect = self.bounds;
    }

    CGImageRef cgimg = [self.noiseContext createCGImage:self.noiseImage fromRect:extentRect];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, self.noiseOpacity);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, cgimg);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
}
```

Basically, I create the `CIImage` in init using a `CIRandomGenerator` as input to a `CIColorMonochrome` filter. Then, when it comes time to draw it, I create a `CGImageRef` out of it using `self.bounds` (the extent is **always** `infinite` or 0), and draw it to the context.

The result is mostly fine, but as you can see in the image, there seems to be some stretching going on. What is happening here?

Comment: It's a bit late, but the code you posted doesn't match the picture. On my iPad Mini and in simulator, this class does what's expected: a layer with random noise. Please post code that actually reproduces the error.

Comment: It did at the time of posting. You may be using a different operating system or SDK. See my solution below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not fixing the original problem, I approached this from a different angle and have duplicated the output. Instead of trying to generate a single image the size of the `self.bounds`, I am now generating an image that is only 64x64, then tiling it using `CGContextDrawTiledImage`. Because I am now sizing it at a fixed size, I could pull some code out of the `drawInContext:` method. And finally, because there was no more image generation done in the draw methods, I was able to make it a static var so it is only ever generated once! Here is the complete class:

```
static CGImageRef   __noiseImage        = nil;
static CGFloat      __noiseImageWidth   = 0.0;
static CGFloat      __noiseImageHeight  = 0.0;

@implementation UANoisyGradientLayer

@synthesize noiseOpacity = _noiseOpacity;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.noiseOpacity = 0.1f;
        self.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            CIContext *noiseContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

            CIFilter *noiseGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
            [noiseGenerator setValue:[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"] valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];
            [noiseGenerator setDefaults];

            CIImage *ciImage = [noiseGenerator outputImage];

            CGRect extentRect = [ciImage extent];
            if (CGRectIsInfinite(extentRect) || CGRectIsEmpty(extentRect)) {
                extentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
            }

            __noiseImage = [noiseContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:extentRect];
            __noiseImageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(__noiseImage);
            __noiseImageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(__noiseImage);
        });
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    [super drawInContext:ctx];

    if (self.noiseOpacity > 0) {

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        CGPathRef path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:self.cornerRadius] CGPath];
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
        CGContextClip(ctx);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
        CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, self.noiseOpacity);


        CGContextDrawTiledImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, __noiseImageWidth, __noiseImageHeight), __noiseImage);

        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }
}

@end
```

**NOTE**: `CIColorMonochrome` and `CIRandomGenerator` require **iOS 6** (or newer). Make sure to include the required frameworks (`CoreImage.framework` and `QuartzCore.framework`).